# android - trying to receive data from php file - app crashes

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm trying to receive data from remote server and insert the data to variable "respond"
but the app crashes... I don't have log , because my emulator doesnt work, and sdk driver's for my phone also doesnt work, so I install the apk file via usb cable...
the compiler doesn't show error.
thanks for help

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String serverURL = "http://www.adoninetwork.com/index.html";
String respond = "test";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverURL);

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try {
         respond = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } 



    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(respond).show();
```

Comment: To get logs via usb cable, use the command `adb logcat`.  That should get you your error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do a network connection on the Main Thread and Android don't allow that, so the system kill your app. You probably have the error [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

You have to use a AsyncTask ([tutorial here](http://android.programmerguru.com/what-is-asynctask-in-android/)) or the Google library Volley ([documentation here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)).

Add your log if you want more explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

check permission in manifest-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```